# How to make an external request/catch the event in javascript on AddToCart button click in Prestashop?

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I'm trying to call an external URL when users adds an item in the shopping cart.
It should work if it's ajax powered cart or classic.

The only way I found is to modify controller/front/CartController.php and do a curl request.

Is it possible to catch it as an event in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the file`/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js`. It's the file that handle everything for the cart. In the first method `overrideButtonsInThePage` you will find the functions called when the "add to cart" buttons are clicked. You can use this to trigger whatever you want, or replicate the event handler in another file.

Comment: indeed, this is a good point to start. I've modified this file but it works only for ajax powered carts. Anyway, here I have another issue:.. i can't get cart id :)

Comment: I don't think it's available as is from javascript. But it's pretty easy to edit the blockcart module to pass it to smarty then output it. Kind of hack-ish but that's the easiest solution I can think of right now.